# Configuring phabricator to allow push over http

Tags: http, mercurial, phabricator

I want to configure Phabricator so I can hg push over http.

For now I configured it as ok, in the repository page appears the command to clone it and in "hosting" configuration I have set it to Read/Write to http (as you can see in the images bellow). Also I have configured the `diffusion.allow-http-auth` to true and the `VCS Password` for my user.

[image: Status of the repository: all ok]

[image: Hosting - Server over HTTP: Read/Write]

I have done a pull from it correctly, and added changes to this local clone.

But when I try to push the initial history/commit, hg show the following error:

```
% hg push http://*********/diffusion/W/web/
pushing to http://*********/diffusion/W/web/
http authorization required
<--- Credentials Ok -->
realm: Phabricator Repositories
abort: operation not supported over http
```

What I'm doing wrong? Http can only be used to pull?

Note: I already know that is better to use ssh, but I can't configure the server to use it by other policies that can't be changed. Also, this Question can be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485732/git-repositories-that-allow-push-pull-over-http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was affecting me is the version of the mercurial in the server was too old. I have updated it to HG 3.0.1 and now I can push through http.

And from the [task](https://secure.phabricator.com/T3046) in Phabricator, this what happened with different versions of mercurial:

- Versions 1.4 to 1.8 will reject the push with abort: operation not supported over http.
- Versions 1.9 to 2.1 accept the push.
- Version 2.2 spills this error message when trying to push (and the contents won't be pushed).
- Versions 2.3 to 3.0 accept the push.

You can see a related task in [Phabricator task T3046](https://secure.phabricator.com/T3046).

Answer (score 0):

In Diffusion User Guide, [Configuring HTTP](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_hosting/#configuring-http) part, you can see some requirements mentioned (which are **not reflected** in your description)

> If you plan to use authenticated HTTP, you need to set diffusion.allow-http-auth in Config. If you don't plan to use HTTP, or plan to use only anonymous HTTP, you can leave this setting disabled.
>
> If you plan to use authenticated HTTP, you'll also need to configure a VCS password in "Settings" -> "VCS Password". This is a different password than your main Phabricator password primarily for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, I have already done it (I forgot to mention it in the question). As I say now in the question I already can clone it.